# Play .WAV under Mono on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, audio

The [Mono 2.6 distribution](http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap) contains System.Media.SoundPlayer, but attempts to play result in no sound (and no errors) on Mac OS X. All I can find with Google search is obscure references to ALSA. I [posted to the Mono-OSX list](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td2133460), but there have been on replies there. I hope someone here has an answer. I think I need to tap into CoreAudio, but don't know how from Mono/C#.

Answer (score 2):

Report this issue to Mono team if you can provide a reproducible environment stably,

http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Comment: Several others have already reported this, so I didn't re-report it.

Answer (score 0):

did you have tryed to use http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpffmpeg/ that libraries, can help you or look in google ffmpeg c# also there's a TOA Framework it's another project to play audio.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look, but I was tryiung to avoid a dependency to a large library. I was hoping for System.Media.SoundPlayer in Mono 2.6 on OS X to work properly. For now I will wait to see if the Mono team addresses this on OS X. But thanks for the reply anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the MonoMac bindings which include bindings for CoreAudio.